# Django passing variable to a form

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to pass a primary key variable straight into a form (foreign key) so the user doesn't have to select it. This is what I have:

I have an HTML button

```
<a href="{% url 'addfraction' pk=botany.botany_id %}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Add Fraction</a>
```

It passes the primary key of the botany table (botany_id) through the urls.py

```
url(r'^addfraction/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.addfraction, name='addfraction'),
```

The pk comes in to the def addfraction

```
def addfraction(request, pk):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = FractionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            return redirect('allbotany')
    else:
        form = FractionForm()
    return render(request, 'fraction/create_fraction.html', {'form': form})
```

And the data in the form is saved to the database.

```
class FractionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Fraction
        fields = (
        #'fraction_id',
        'botany_id',
        'proportion_analysed',
        'soil_volume',
        'sample_volume',
        'sample_weight',
        )
```

botany_id is a foreign key, it becomes a dropdown box, this needs to be greyed out and contain the botany_id pk. Where have I gone wrong? Any pointers welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can eliminate `botany_id` from the form fields, and you can just assign it to the post instance directly from your `addfraction` function in `views.py` without involving your user in the process.

Just add this line before `post.save()`:

```
 botany = get_object_or_404(Botany, pk=pk)
 post.botany_id = botany
```

Hope that is what you're trying to do, good luck!

Comment: That was my initial thought but it returns the error: Cannot assign "'1'": "Fraction.botany_id" must be a "Botany" instance.
I put the post.botany_id = pk between the post = form.save(...) and post.save()

Comment: @GaryNobles Try it now, I edited something. Make sure to also import your Botany Model in views.py